# RavenDB returns stale results after delete

Tags: ravendb

We seem to have verified that RavenDB is getting stale results even when we use various flavors of "WaitForNonStaleResults". Following is the fully-functional sample code (written as a standalone test so that you can copy/paste it and run it as is).

```
public class Cart
{
  public virtual string Email { get; set; }
}

[Test]
public void StandaloneTestForPostingOnStackOverflow()
{
  var testDocument = new Cart { Email = "test@abc.com" };
  var documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore { RunInMemory = true };
  documentStore.Initialize();

  using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
  {
    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
    {
      session.Store(testDocument);
      session.SaveChanges();
      transaction.Complete();
    }

    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
    {
      var documentToDelete = session
        .Query<Cart>()
        .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite())
        .First(c => c.Email == testDocument.Email);

      session.Delete(documentToDelete);
      session.SaveChanges();
      transaction.Complete();
    }

    RavenQueryStatistics statistics;

    var actualCount = session
      .Query<Cart>()
      .Statistics(out statistics)
      .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite())
      .Count(c => c.Email == testDocument.Email);

    Assert.IsFalse(statistics.IsStale);
    Assert.AreEqual(0, actualCount);
  }
}
```

We have tried every flavor of WaitForNonStaleResults and there is no change. Waiting for non-stale results seems to work fine for the update, but not for the delete.

**Update**

Some things which I have tried:

1. Using separate sessions for each action. Outcome: no difference. Same successes and fails.
2. Putting `Thread.Current.Sleep(500)` before the final query. Outcome: success. If I sleep the thread for a half second, the count comes back zero like it should.

Comment: Where is testDocument declared? Are you sure documentToDelete isn't null? Is it possible that you need to close your session and do your query with a new session?

Comment: The testDocument is initialized in the very first line of the function. As to the new session, I should not have to open a new session to get current query results, but in any case I have already tried that. I will edit the post to contain additional information observations.

Comment: That's interesting that sleeping for half a second works. The only other thing I can think of is that it's either a bug, or you need a better index. What version of RavenDB are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Re: my comment above on stale results, AllowNonAuthoritiveInformation wasn't working. Needing to put WaitForNonStaleResults in each query, which is the usual "answer" to this issue, feels like a massive "code smell" (as much as I normally hate the term, it seems completely appropriate here).

The only real solution I've found so far is:

```
var store = new DocumentStore(); // do whatever
store.DatabaseCommands.DisableAllCaching();
```

Performance suffers accordingly, but I think slower performance is far less of a sin than unreliable if not outright inaccurate results.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I recently ran across this problem as well.  I was able to work around it by changing the convention on the `DocumentStore` used by the session to make it wait for non stale as of last write:

```
session.DocumentStore.DefaultQueryingConsistency = ConsistencyOptions.AlwaysWaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite;
```

This made it so that I didn't have to customize every query run after.  That said, I believe this only works for queries.  It definitely doesn't work on patches as I have found out through testing.

I would also be careful about this and only use it around the code that's needed as it can cause performance issues.  You can set the store back to its default with the following:

```
session.DocumentStore.DefaultQueryingConsistency = ConsistencyOptions.None;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't related to deletes, it is related to using `TransactionScope`. The problem here is that DTC transaction complete in an asynchronous manner.

To fix this issue, what you need to do is call:

```
 session.Advanced.AllowNonAuthoritiveInformation = false;
```

Which will force RavenDB to wait for the transaction to complete.

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention to this question. We greatly appreciate it!
Unfortunately, adding that line did not fix the problem. There is still a disconnect between the timings. We also added a call to `ExecuteAllPendingLazyOperations` in the hopes that that might help, but it did not. I understand that transactions complete asynchronously, but is there any way to force a request to wait for pending transactions to complete? I thought that was the purpose of the `WaitForNonStale...` functions.

Comment: I'm having the inverse issue here as well, stale results coming back no matter what I do unless I initialise a new document store (completely unacceptable solution). If something is added or deleted it picks that up fine, but anything that is updated just returns the stale content as if the update never happened until a new document store is created. 3 days wasted on this now... argh...